# my code could not able to detect undefined and null values can someone please correct it?

Tags: javascript

```js
var isTopper = false

var marksobtained = window.prompt('please enter the marks obtained ')

if (marksobtained == undefined || marksobtained == null || marksobtained == '') {

  alert('invalid')
} else if (marksobtained < 0 || marksobtained > 100) {
  alert('enter between 0 to 100')
} else {
  marksobtained = Number(marksobtained)
  var totalmarks = 100
  var percentage = (marksobtained / totalmarks) * 100


  if (percentage > 90) {
    isTopper = true
  } else {
    isTopper = false
  }
  alert(isTopper)
}
```

Comment: What's not working exactly?

Comment: `prompt` will never return null or undefined...

Comment: it is working now can you explain what changes u made that it started working

Answer (score 0):

I don't why your code is not working for you(as it is working for us), I just made few modifications in your code like replace `if (marksobtained == undefined || marksobtained == null || marksobtained == '')` this with this `if (!marksobtained)` and

As you are asking only one subject marks you don't have to calculate percentage you can directly tell on the basis of marks whether he/she is topper or not(I am saying this only because you are asking only one subject marks and that marks is in between 1 to 100)

```js
var isTopper = false

var marksobtained = window.prompt('please enter the marks obtained ')

if (!marksobtained || isNaN(marksobtained)) {
  alert('invalid')
} else if (marksobtained < 0 || marksobtained > 100) {
  alert('enter between 0 to 100')
} else {
  marksobtained = Number(marksobtained);
  if (marksobtained > 90) {
    isTopper = true
  } else {
    isTopper = false
  }
  alert(isTopper)
}
```

Comment: but it is giving the false answer whenever i'm giving  character value can you fix that . i want the in valid response whenever i type the character

Answer (score -1):

I dont know where is your problem. Please provide some details. `alert('invalid')` is working correctly and being called when value is empty string.

Instead of

```
if (marksobtained == undefined || marksobtained == null || marksobtained == '')
```

You can simply use

```
if (!marksobtained) { ...
```

Comment: but in case if i take the character value as input it is giving me false as answer but i want invalid input as answer